# Get time series in dataset on plot using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset something like:

```
Asset Name  Time    Usage
A   10:39:49    CPU usage
A   10:46:35    CPU usage
B   11:06:55    CPU usage
C   11:24:05    Memory usage
A   11:31:35    Memory usage
B   13:46:17    CPU usage
A   10:35:43    Virtual Machine Failover Failed
C   10:40:55    CPU usage
B   10:45:05    CPU usage
A   11:31:35    CPU usage
B   10:59:44    Memory usage
B   11:44:36    CPU usage
A   11:49:22    Memory usage
```

I want to plot Asset Name vs Time on the basis of Usage.
I used the code:

```
ggplot(DTPlot, aes(DTPlot$Time, Asset.Name, color = Usage)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_time() + xlab("") + ylab("Asset Name")
```

The time I am getting on X-Axis ranges from 00:00:00 to 00:00:24. How can I get the time series in the dataset on the plot as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated but: don't use $ for column names inside `aes`. Just `aes(Time, Asset.Name)`.

Comment: Changed that. But, doesn't help achieve the objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
df %>%
    mutate(Time = as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%H:%M:%S")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Time, Asset.Name, color = Usage)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(x = "", y = "Asset Name")
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
df <-read.table(text =
    "'Asset Name'  Time    Usage
A   10:39:49    'CPU usage'
A   10:46:35    'CPU usage'
B   11:06:55    'CPU usage'
C   11:24:05    'Memory usage'
A   11:31:35    'Memory usage'
B   13:46:17    'CPU usage'
A   10:35:43    'Virtual Machine Failover Failed'
C   10:40:55    'CPU usage'
B   10:45:05    'CPU usage'
A   11:31:35    'CPU usage'
B   10:59:44    'Memory usage'
B   11:44:36    'CPU usage'
A   11:49:22    'Memory usage'", header = T)
```

Comment: Heyy!! Thank you so much!!